# Nodejs reading database query throws error for individual field

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mongoose

Hi I am trying to read a field from query but keeps giving `undefined` error.

I have following

```
var book=mongoose.model("book",{
      name: {type: String},
      author: {type: String}
  });

con.query('select * from booktable', function(err, result){
          if(!err) {
              //it shows 10 book records in result
              console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null))
               var temp=util.inspect(result, false, null);
               var tc=temp.length;
               for(i=0; i<tc; i++){
              //i get error here saying can not read property '0' of undefined
                 console.log(temp[i].author);
                }
              } else {
               console.log(err);
            }
          }
```

I get error where I try to log just author value on console.

```
 Error say   TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
```

So as soon as it goes in the for loop it throws error.

Please let me know how to fix it. Either read author values directly from result or through util.

Thanks

Comment: can you print `temp` and paste here ?

Comment: Sorry can't paste its on work computer at office but exactly this is what it says "console.log(temp[i].author); TypeError: Cannot read property "0" of undefined."  so what it is saying is that temp[0].author undefined.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below. it may work

```
 for(var i=0; i<tc; i++){
     //i get error here saying can not read property '0' of undefined
     console.log(temp[i].author);
}
```

Comment: The property of 0 error went away but still the value says Undefined.

Comment: what is the `tc` size ?

Comment: actual tc is 204 but I have made tc=3 to debug

Comment: are you sure `temp` is giving array ? if not, and if it is JSON then please use JSON.parse(temp)

Comment: You mean like set var t=JSON.parse(temp) than loop though with t[i].author?

Comment: yes, if your response is string and want to use JSON